# Gets redirected to default app route when deleting comment using Angular JS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am developing an application using Laravel and AngularJS where users may write and delete their comments.

On the home screen, the user is able to view and delete all of his/her comments and when they do the list should be updated.

My problem is that when I press the delete button I am redirected to the login page which is the default route.

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : '/login' });
```

I'm using laravels resource controller

```
Route::resource('comment', 'CommentController');
```

When I go to the home page again the comment is successfully deleted.

My comment service uses this to delete a comment:

```
app.factory('CommentService', function($http) {
  return {
    destroy: function(id) {
      return $http.delete('comment/' + id);
    }
  };
});
```

In the home controller I have created this function to delete the comment.

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $location, AuthenticationService, CommentService) {

  $scope.deleteComment = function(id) {

    CommentService.destroy(id).success(function() {
      CommentService.get().success(function(data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
        $scope.order = 'end_date';
      });
    });
  };
```

How can I prevent the site from redirecting to the login page when I delete a comment?

The best would be to redirect to the most recent page if I am logged in, and if I'm not I should be redirected to the login page. 
(e.g. if I were at the home page then I will be redirected to the home page if I type something in the url that doesn't exist or if I delete a comment)

The login system is created from these tutorials by David Mosher:

[Introduction to Angular JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ILQOFAgaXE)

[End to End with Angular JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqAyiqUs93c)

[Security with Angular JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18ifoT-Id54)

Comment: Did you checked the response of DELETE call?. Is it really a json or you are getting a redirect "Location" header?

Comment: @ashu I'm not sure how to check the response. Can you please specify how I can check the response, and/or provide an example?

Comment: You can check the same in network tab in chrome. Press f12 to activate the dev tools. check out [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console--net-28167) link for more details on usage.

Comment: @ashu Under the response tab for the delete call I get {"success":true}.

Comment: what about the get comments call?

Comment: It returns an array with a json for each comment

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you've figured it out, but in case someone lands here, below one thing which could be responsible (and was in the code I just finished debugging):

```
<a href="#" ng-click="deleteComment()">x</a>
```

This will do both run deleteComment and follow the route `#` . Adding `href="#"` (or `href=""` for that matter) is a bad habit, a `<a></a>` can be used without href, and in this case, it should. So this should work without redirect:

```
<a ng-click="deleteComment()">x</a>
```

Hope it helps anyone who'd land here ;)